# Proper promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to use a series of requests to build a model before binding it to my view.  I am having a hard time understanding how I can leverage the response of one request to make the next request.  My issue is that my "sponsor" and "manager" properties resolve as a promise and not the response.

> ```
> $.get("/projects/1")
> .then(function(data){
>   var manager = $.get("/employees/" + data.ProjectManagerId);
>
>   data.manager = manager;
>   return data;
> })
> .then(function(data){
>   var sponsor = $.get("/employees/" + data.ProjectSponsorId);
>
>   data.sponsor = sponsor;
>   return data;
> })
> .then(function(data){
>   //Bind data to view
>
>   //data.manager is a promise
>   //data.sponsor is a promise
> })
> .done();
> ```

How can I ensure the data is returned instead of the promise?

Comment: Are you aware that this is tagged Q but there is not a single Q promise in here?

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I was using Q in my app but ended up removing the references in my simplified example.  I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the manager and sponsor requests can be paralellized (executed simultaneously).

I'd slap a `when` in there:

```
$.get("/projects/1")
.then(function(data){
  var manager_req = $.get("/employees/" + data.ProjectManagerId);
  var sponsor_req = $.get("/employees/" + data.ProjectSponsorId);

  return $.when(data, manager_req, sponsor_req);
})
.then(function(data, manager, sponsor){
  data.sponsor = sponsor;
  data.manager = manager;
  return data;
})
.done(function(data){
  //Bind data to view

  //data.manager is resolved
  //data.sponsor is resolved
});
```

---

Nesting the when promise deals a little bit better with `data`:

```
$.get("/projects/1")
.then(function(data){
  var manager_req = $.get("/employees/" + data.ProjectManagerId);
  var sponsor_req = $.get("/employees/" + data.ProjectSponsorId);

  return $.when(manager_req, sponsor_req).then(function(manager, sponsor){
    data.sponsor = sponsor;
    data.manager = manager;
    return data;
  });
})
.done(function(data){
  //Bind data to view

  //data.manager is resolved
  //data.sponsor is resolved
});
```

Comment: Does $.when kick the requests off and wait for their completion before allowing the return?  It seems like that is the bit I was missing, although I agree on the parallel bit.

Comment: `$.get` does the request. `$.when` merely synchronizes the two requests. It returns a promise that is resolved when _all_ it's inputs are resolved. If an input is not a promise (like `data` in the first sample) it counts as a resolved value.